# Ошибка при запуске скрипта python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""mafia party game bot"""
import logging
import sys

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from host import Host
from game import GameStatus

token = sys.argv[1] #12 строка

logging.basicConfig(filename='bot.log',level=logging.INFO)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 12, in <module>
    token = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Каким образом ты запускаешь bot.py?

Comment: Так иногда бывает, когда скрипт стащишь где-нибудь, а что он делает не понимаешь.

Comment: запускаю python bot.py

Answer (score 0):

Данный бот принимает параметры командной строки, где второй аргумент это токен.
Достаточно изменить значение токена на токен бота:
token = "тут должен быть токен бота"

Comment: ERROR:telegram.ext.dispatcher:No error handlers are registered, logging exception. теперь этот ошибка в логе